# VBA Excel Pass a variable name to a sub; update the value of the variable name in the sub

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to pass the name of a variable to a SUB and then update the value of the variable in the SUB but I am not getting it right.

I have a global variable

```
    Dim booLastNm as Boolean
```

I have a function

```
    Public Sub FilltheForm(myCTL As Control, intNum As Integer, Optional booName As String)
        myCTL.Value = myArray(1, intNum)
        If booName <> "" Then booName = True
        MsgBox booName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & booLastNm
    End Sub
```

I call the function in a combobox change routine:

```
    FilltheForm Me.boxLastNm, 1, "booLastNm"
```

It correctly changes the userform field "Me.boxLastNm" from myArray(1, 1).  I also want the value of the global variable "booLastNm" set to True.  However, the value of "booName" is being set to True while the value of "booLastNm" remains set to "False".  How do I pass the name of the variable I want to change (in this case "booLastNm") to a function so that the value gets changed instead of the variable "booName"?  I have about 148 variables that I am reading from an Excel spreadsheet and am trying to dump them into a multi-page userform for data validation.  The "boo" variables are Boolean variables that I check upon page change; if selected Boolean variables are set to false, I want the user to make corrections on the current page before advancing to the next page.

Comment: `If booName <> "" Then booLastNm = True`

Comment: The problem with that, Scott, is that I have 148 possible variables to pass to the function.  How do I extract the name of the variable, which I pass as an optional variable, and correctly set the value of the variable name to True?

Comment: You cannot do that, unfortunately. You will need to specific each variable to set. You can use a case statement to do in the function but you will have to explicitly set the value of each variable in that case statement.

Comment: Well that stinks!  I was trying to avoid having to hard code the boolean variable names in an If...Then...Else scenario or having a Select Case with 148 cases.  Got any ideas on how I can improve this?

Comment: Um. Don't use 148 boolean variables? That's one idea. Is it absolutely necessary to do that or do you just need to test a condition on each run and then return some result based on that test? The best way to program is to write procedures that do one thing really well and combine them as needed. If you just need to test something based on arguments that you pass then do that, get in and out and code more decisions on the results. You may find more patterns upon which you can build more functions to process.

Comment: You can create a global scripting dictionary instance, then you can do (e.g.) `dict(booName) = True`

Comment: You could also use a class module to hold your variables. Then you can use `Callbyname` to set the variables using the name. Note I said *could*, not *should*. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass by reference.

```
Public Sub FilltheForm(myCTL As Control, intNum As Integer, Optional ByRef booName As String)
```

However, in your example you are using `booName` as both a `Boolean` and a `String` (the function signature above is a copy of yours). Also you don't re-assign anything to `BooLastNm`, so that would be why it is not changing.

If you are passing `ByRef`, worthwhile checking out using a `Variant`, so that you can also use `IsMissing()` to give some flexibility in a UDF. Might not be relevant in this case but learning things is always handy.